# Can I set a specific border size for JFrame when it contains GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, awt

[image]

This is a sample class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Image {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
      Layout lo = new Layout();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.getContentPane().add(lo.getGUI(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

This is the Layout class that comes with it

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Layout {

    private JPanel p;

    public Layout() {
        p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5, 1, 1));
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JLabel[][] lbs = new JLabel[5][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                lbs[i][j] = new JLabel(".", JLabel.CENTER);
                lbs[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                lbs[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                p.add(lbs[i][j]);
            }
    }

    public JComponent getGUI() {
        return p;
    }
}
```

Result of the code is this:

[image]

So, my question is how can I size a fixed size like the image above? I want to later on add components like the buttons on it later on. I cannot figure out how to set a fixed size of the JPanel after applying a GridLayout to it. I added GridLayout to it because I need it to display something similar to chess. I will not be touching anything except for the buttons. The JPanel is for view that's it.

I should mention I will be changing the dots in the middle of the grid to other symbols(such as ! or #) to represent objects in the 5x5 space. I use JLabel to present the objects. If I use GridBagLayout, all the symbols are squashed together in 1 area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I 100% understand what you're asking, but if your desire is for empty space around the grid, then perhaps what you're looking for is an EmptyBorder, easily obtained via `BorderFactor.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap);` where gap is the size of the border, one that of course can be a unique value for each side.

Don't forget to nest JPanels, each using its own layout, for maximal layout effect. For example the following GUI is produced by the code underneath:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayoutTest extends JPanel {
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int SIDES = 5;
    private static final int GAP = 25;
    private static final Color BG = Color.WHITE;
    private LayoutPanel layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel(CELL_WIDTH, SIDES);

    public LayoutTest() {
        setBackground(BG);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, GAP, GAP));
        btnPanel.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        btnPanel.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        btnPanel.setBackground(BG);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(layoutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LayoutTest mainPanel = new LayoutTest();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class LayoutPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
    private int sides = 5;
    private static final int INNER_GAP = 1;
    private static final Color CELL_BG = Color.WHITE;

    public LayoutPanel(int cellWidth, int sides) {
        setBackground(BG);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BG));
        this.sides = sides;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(sides, sides, INNER_GAP, INNER_GAP));
        Dimension cellDim = new Dimension(cellWidth, cellWidth);
        for (int i = 0; i < sides * sides; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(".", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.setPreferredSize(cellDim);
            label.setBackground(CELL_BG);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            add(label);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the picture on the bottom is the JPanel that fills the entire JFrame. I want the JPanel not to take up the entire JFrame so that I have some space to add extra components such as buttons

Comment: @NoobestPros: you need to nest JPanels to achieve this effect, and to allow simple creation of complex GUI's. Please see code in edit to answer.

Comment: For example, as @camickr stated in a deleted comment, posted as I was creating this example, if you nest your GridLayout-using JPanel within a BorderLayout using one, you can create the desired GUI.

Comment: nesting as in stacking jpanel on top of jpanel?

Comment: @NoobestPros: nesting as I've shown in the example code above. The outside JPanel uses BorderLayout and holds the inner GridLayout using JPanel in the BorderLayout.CENTER position.